# How to have two polling running WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private async void InitialiseApp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // The first two function run once
    await InitManifest();
    await InitResult();

    await UpdateManifest(_ManifestToken.Token);
    await UpdateResult(_ResultToken.Token);
}

public async static Task UpdateManifest(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (true)
    {
       await Task.Delay(45000);
    }
}
```

I am in a situation where I have two types of json data.

First json(has multiple links(object)):
{"name":"Link 1","id":22,"url":"link1.json"}

Second json(has multiple person object):
{"name":"john","age":22,"class":"mca"}

The First json contains links that contains the second types of json data.

I would like to put the name of all the links in a `Listbox` and I have a second 'Listbox' that display data from the selected item in the first 'Listbox'.

My greatest challenge is that both json updates the first one will poll every 45 second and the second ¬Listbox¬ poll very 15 seconds.

I have created a function which initialise the data for both the `Listbox`'s asynchronously, successfully. But now I would like to update both 'Listbox' independently, without blocking on the UI thread. I have true calling two polls but I have set a break point and I realise the code is not getting to the second poll. I understand why but I am not sure how to get around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you `await` your tasks. Which means you *wait* for them to finish. And you don't want to wait for them to finish because they never do, so don't wait for them. Remove the `await` keyword in front of those tasks you don't want to wait for.

You may or may not want to have the resulting tasks as variables and you can do so by assigning the result of the method to a `Task`.

Your current problem will be fixed by removing the `await` keyword from those lines that you don't want to wait for. Other problems will follow, as is common with multithreading in UI.

Comment: What you are saying is both `Update`  functions do not need to be async ? even though I am making `HttpClient` request to get the latest data in the while loop?

Comment: They need to create a new `Task` so that it works asynchronously. You don't necessarily need the `async` keyword for that and you certainly don't need to `await` them because that is precisely what you *don't* want to do.

Comment: Because `UpdateManifest` is no longer async, how do I make sure the HTTP request gets completed before it starts again with out blocking the UI?

Comment: Have you got a link to an example of the implementation? because what I tried (when I edit your answer) solve the problem of continuation the application but when I set a break point at the start of my `UpdateManifest` function I got Not hit.